# Combining results of two tables in mongoid/mongo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Hi guys what would be the best way to combine results of two mongoid queries.

My issue is that I would like to know active users, A user can send a letter and a notification, both are separate table and a user if he sends either the letter or the notification is considered active. What I want to know is how many active users were there per month.

right now what I can think of is doing this

```
Letter.collection.aggregate([
                       { '$match': {}.merge(opts) },
                       { '$sort': { 'created_at': 1 } },
                       {
                         '$group': {
                           _id: '$customer_id',
                           first_notif_sent: {
                             '$first': {
                               'day': { '$dayOfMonth': '$created_at' },
                               'month': { '$month': '$created_at' },
                               'year': { '$year': '$created_at' }
                             }
                           }
                         }
                       }])
Notification.collection.aggregate([
                       { '$match': {}.merge(opts) },
                       { '$sort': { 'created_at': 1 } },
                       {
                         '$group': {
                           _id: '$customer_id',
                           first_notif_sent: {
                             '$first': {
                               'day': { '$dayOfMonth': '$created_at' },
                               'month': { '$month': '$created_at' },
                               'year': { '$year': '$created_at' }
                             }
                           }
                         }
                       }])
```

What I am looking for is to get the minimum of the dates and then combine the results and get the count. Right now I can get the results and loop over each of them and create a new list. But I wanted to know if there is a way to do it in mongo directly.

**EDIT**

For letters

```
  def self.get_active(tenant_id)
    map = %{
      function() {
        emit(this.customer_id, new Date(this.created_at))
      }
    }

    reduce = %{
      function(key, values) {
        return new Date(Math.min.apply(null, values))
      }
    }
    where(tenant_id: tenant_id).map_reduce(map, reduce).out(reduce: "#{tenant_id}_letter_notification")
  end
```

Notifications

```
def self.get_active(tenant_id)
    map = %{
      function() {
        emit(this.customer_id, new Date(this.updated_at))
      }
    }

    reduce = %{
      function(key, values) {
        return new Date(Math.min.apply(null, values))
      }
    }
    where(tenant_id: tenant_id, transferred: true).map_reduce(map, reduce).out(reduce: "#{tenant_id}_outgoing_letter_standing_order_balance")
  end
```

This is what I am thinking of going with, one of the reason is that, lookup does not work with my version of mongo.

Comment: Its only possible if you've some kind of relationship between two collection.

Comment: The only thing that is common is that they have the same customer_id, but it could also be something like the customer created a new notification, or a new letter, and I would like to get the first created at of either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the customer created a new notification, or a new letter, and I would like to get the first created at of either.

Let's address this first as a foundation. Given examples of document schema as below:

Document schema in `Letter` collection:

```
{ _id: <ObjectId>,
  customer_id: <integer>,
  created_at: <date> }
```

And, document schema in `Notification` collection:

```
{ _id: <ObjectId>,
  customer_id: <integer>,
  created_at: <date> }
```

You can utilise [aggregation pipeline $lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to join the two collections. For example using [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) :

```
db.letter.aggregate([
    {"$group":{"_id":"$customer_id", tmp1:{"$max":"$created_at"}}}, 
    {"$lookup":{from:"notification", 
              localField:"_id",
              foreignField:"customer_id", 
              as:"notifications"}}, 
    {"$project":{customer_id:"$_id", 
               _id:0,
               latest_letter:"$tmp1", 
               latest_notification: {"$max":"$notifications.created_at"}}},
    {"$addFields":{"latest": 
                {"$cond":[{"$gt":["$latest_letter", "$latest_notification"]}, 
                 "$latest_letter", 
                 "$latest_notification"]}}},
    {"$sort":{latest:-1}}
], {cursor:{batchSize:100}})
```

The output of the above [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) is a list of customers in sorted order of `created_at` field from either `Letter` or `Notification`. Example output documents:

```
  {
    "customer_id": 0,
    "latest_letter": ISODate("2017-12-19T07:00:08.818Z"),
    "latest_notification": ISODate("2018-01-26T13:43:56.353Z"),
    "latest": ISODate("2018-01-26T13:43:56.353Z")
  },
  {
    "customer_id": 4,
    "latest_letter": ISODate("2018-01-04T18:55:26.264Z"),
    "latest_notification": ISODate("2018-01-25T02:05:19.035Z"),
    "latest": ISODate("2018-01-25T02:05:19.035Z")
  }, ...
```

> What I want to know is how many active users were there per month

To achieve this, you can just replace the last stage ([$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)) of the above aggregation pipeline with [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). For example:

```
db.letter.aggregate([
    {"$group":{"_id":"$customer_id", tmp1:{$max:"$created_at"}}}, 
    {"$lookup":{from:"notification", 
              localField:"_id",
              foreignField:"customer_id", 
              as:"notifications"}}, 
    {"$project":{customer_id:"$_id", 
               _id:0,
               latest_letter:"$tmp1", 
               latest_notification: {"$max":"$notifications.created_at"}}},
    {"$addFields":{"latest": 
                {"$cond":[{"$gt":["$latest_letter", "$latest_notification"]}, 
                 "$latest_letter", 
                 "$latest_notification"]}}},
    {"$group":{_id:{month:{"$month": "$latest"}, 
                  year:{"$year": "$latest"}}, 
             active_users: {"$sum": "$customer_id"}
            }
    }
],{cursor:{batchSize:10}})
```

Where the example output would be as below:

```
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 10,
      "year": 2017
    },
    "active_users": 9
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 1,
      "year": 2018
    },
    "active_users": 18
  },
```

Comment: Hey I have updated my question since lookup does not work with my version of mongo, I also did update the mongo version but the query was taking quite a long time.

Comment: The operator `$lookup` is available since MongoDB v3.2 (released in 2015, current version is v3.6), if your MongoDB version is older than v3.2, I strongly recommend to upgrade. If the aggregation query is taking a long time being performed on your server, then you should either 1) Consider re-designing your [document data model](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/data-modeling/) to be more optimised for your use case 2) Scale up your servers (horizontally or vertically).